# EROOR AL REINSTALAR WORDPRESS

Tags: base-de-datos, wordpress

estoy reinstalando wordpress en mi equipo local.

Anteriormente había instalado la última versión y estaba funcionando correctamente, sin embargo, a fin de trabajar con una versión más antigua, desinstalé wordpresss y ahora al querer instalar la versión antigua me aparece el siguiente error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "DB_USER" in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\wp-includes\load.php:352 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\web\wp-settings.php(79): require_wp_db() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\web\wp-admin\setup-config.php(33): require('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\wp-includes\load.php on line 352

la linea 352 a la que se hace referencia menciona lo siguiente:

```
$wpdb = new wpdb( DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME, DB_HOST );
```

Si alguien me puede orientar, gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Tienes wp-config.php bien puesto?  Diria que esa constante `DB_USER`deberia estar alli con un `define`

Comment: @masterguru tenías razón, por alguna razón  la versión antigua que estaba tratando de instalar, no tenía el wp-config.php y es por eso que me aparecía ese error

Comment: Borra la pregunta pues, ha sido un desliz sin más :-)